# Set up HTML Signature with custom fonts in iOS Mail?

Tags: html, ios, email, fonts

I have a HTML signature with custom fonts in my emails. On my desktop everything is fine. Even when I send an email to my address and check it on iOS everything is fine.

But when I want to set up this signature in iOS Mail, I copy the signature from my email and insert it into the signature option in iOS and can immediately see that the custom fonts are not copied. Is it possible to set up a HTML signature in iOS with custom fonts?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. 
You can perform an undo action (i.e. shake your iPhone) just after pasting the signature that you copied from an email.

This will take out all the code that iOS Mail inserts by default in your pasted signature and you should see it rendered just fine.

Comment: This is absolutely ludicrous - but it works - should be the accepted answer

Comment: @LukeBailey indeed it’s ludicrous! Haven’t found other way though